# How can I network state change real time image on android?

Tags: android

I want network state display images in real time

**For example:** Recently network state is ethernet connect, I want show ethernet image.
The screen does not change, if the network connection is changed, it should be changed.

I think create receiver class. But changing the network, app is stop.

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  ImageView ethernet;

  ImageView unableNetwork;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ethernet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    unableNetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();

    if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {   //error
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ethernet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    unableNetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();

    if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

*ChangeReceiver.class*

```
public class ChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ImageView ethernet;
    ImageView unableNetwork;
    View v;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    ethernet = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); //error

    unableNetwork = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();

    if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else { //error
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        unableNetwork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash is because the view is not created, try this:

```
public class ChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    ImageView ethernet;
    ImageView unableNetwork;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

         View v = ((Activity) context);
         ethernet = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); //error

         unableNetwork = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();
.....
```

And if your want you can use a thread, for more performance:

```
public class ChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    ImageView ethernet;
    ImageView unableNetwork;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run(){
                    View v = ((Activity) context);
                    ethernet = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); //error

                    unableNetwork = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
               }
         });
         int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();
.....
```

I hope I have helped, and sorry my bad English.